# How can I get a function that is "approximately similar" to the part I care about in another function?

Tags: inverse-function, approximation-theory, lambert-w

I have a function f(x)=$(a+bx)e^{-cx}, x\ge0$ where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are constants, and $c>0$.

How can I get a function that is "approximately the same" as the part after the hump?

I need this so I can get the inverse of it for a computer program; taking the inverse of the function in its current form results in some sorcery that I can't comprehend.

I don't really care about precision close to the hump, but it does matter further away.

Just by playing around in Desmos with my limited mathematical knowledge for a while, I found that $\frac 1 {e^x+1}$ matches close enough to what I'm looking for. Below is a picture of the somewhat arbitrary values I used to come close. I figured that the top of the orange line is probably going to be around twice the maximum value of $f$, so $a$ is the value of $f$ where the derivative is $0$.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$
$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}\def\W{\operatorname{W}}\def\Wp{\operatorname{W_0}}\def\Wm{\operatorname{W_{-1}}}\def\Catalan{\mathsf{Catalan}}$

\begin{align} 
f(x)&=(a+bx)\exp(-cx)
,\quad 
x\ge0
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}
where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are constants, and $c>0$.

There is absolutely no need to reinvent the wheel in this case,
since there is a solution for $f(x)=y$:

\begin{align}
x&=
-\frac ab-\frac1c\cdot\W\left(-\frac{cy}b
\,\exp\left(-\frac{ac}b\right)\right)
\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align}

in terms of
[Lambert $\W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
(also known as ProductLog),
with well-known behavior,
which is available in many programming systems.
There is just a few things to note:
the number of real solutions of \eqref{1}
depends on the value of the argument of $\W(z)$
in \eqref{2}.

\begin{align}
z&=-\frac{cy}b
\,\exp\left(-\frac{ac}b\right)
\tag{3}\label{3}
\end{align}

and, depending on its value we have

\begin{align}
1)\ 
z&\ge0:
\quad \text{there is one real solution,}
\quad
x=-\frac ab-\frac1c\cdot\Wp(z)
,\\
2)\ 
z&\in(-\tfrac1e,0):
\quad \text{there are two real solutions,}
\\
x_0&=-\frac ab-\frac1c\cdot\Wp(z)
\quad\text{and}\quad
x_1=-\frac ab-\frac1c\cdot\Wm(z)
,\\
3)\ 
z&=-\tfrac1e:
\quad \text{there is one real solution,}
\\
x&=-\frac ab-\frac1c\cdot\Wp(-\tfrac1e)
=-\frac ab-\frac1c\cdot\Wm(-\tfrac1e)
=-\frac ab+\frac1c
\\
4)\ 
z&<-\tfrac1e:
\quad \text{there is no real solutions}
\end{align}
where $\Wp$ is the principal branch
and $\Wm$ is the other real branch
of the Lambert $\W$ function.

Don't be scared with this "branch" term -
consider these two branches as
just two real functions. Usually they
are available either as two distinct function names,
for example, `W0` and `Wm1`,
or as one function with extra parameter,
for example `W(z)` for $\Wp(z)$
and `W(z,-1)`  for $\Wm(z)$, like in `python`:

```
from scipy.special import lambertw as W
print (W(-0.2).real, W(-0.2,-1).real)
# -0.25917110181907377 -2.5426413577735265
```

$\endgroup$

Comment: Thank you for your answer; unfortunately, where I am going to be using this, there is no Lambert $W$ function I can use, not even any external library that I could find.

Comment: @Freddy:  Really? What software are you going to use?
Even though, it's pretty easy to 
[implement $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Numerical_evaluation) 
using [Halley's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley%27s_method). 
Or just adapt the source code from, say, 
[GSL - GNU Scientific Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl).